# How to test _escaped_fragment solution

Tags: seo, google-search-console

We have just implemented the _escaped_fragment solution in our testing environment along with a headless browser (phantom.js) to make our site crawlable by google.

The issue is I cannot find any solution for how to test this before pushing this change to our production environment.

The fetch as google link in webmaster tools doesn't work.  Is there another way we can test this quickly instead of waiting for the google crawler to crawl our site?

Answer (score 3):

You could write a bookmarklet that mucks with the URL of the page.  It would replaces the `#!` with `?_escaped_fragment=` and URL encodes the hash bang params.   Then you could at least manually go through your site, activate the bookmarklet on any page and verify that you get the content that you expect.